# AS3: Sprite following a Path in high speed

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite

First of all sorry for some english mistakes. Portuguese is my first language(I am from Brazil)

Im trying to make a space game from scratch in AS3 and the way to move the ship is like in the game Air Traffic Chief.

I succeed at some point. But when the ship is very fast it start to shake and its not very smooth and clean as I want.

Here is what i have done: http://megaswf.com/s/2437744

As the code is very big so I pasted in pastebin: pastebin.com/1YVZ23WX
I also wrote some english documentation.

This is my first game and my first post here. I really hope you guys can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
As the code is very big i will try to clarify here.

When the user MouseDown and MouseMove the ship every coordinate is passed to an array.
When the user MouseUP this array is passed to a function that fix the array.

For example: If the distance between two coordinates is greater than 5px, the function creates a coordinate in the middle of the two coordinates.

if I take this function off the problem seen to be solved. But if the user move the mouse very slow it still happens. It also creates a problem that i was trying to solve with that function. as the distance of the two coordinates are very big when the ship arrive in one coordinate most of the line path disappear.

I uploaded a version without the function that fixes the array. http://megaswf.com/s/2437775

I think there is 2 ways for solving this problem

1- Try to fix the noise in the array of coordinates 2- Take off the function that create an coordinate between two points and try to fix the problem of the line path disappear.

Here is the 2 important functions:

this function moves the ship

```
    private function mover():void 
    {
        if (caminhoCoords[0]!=null) // caminhoCoords is the array that contain the path
        {

            var angulo:Number = Math.atan2(this.y - caminhoCoords[0][1], this.x - caminhoCoords[0][0]);
            this.rotation = angulo / (Math.PI / 180);
            this.x = this.x - velocidade * (Math.cos(angulo)); 
            this.y = this.y - velocidade * (Math.sin(angulo));

            var testex:Number = Math.abs(this.x - caminhoCoords[0][0]); //test to see the distance between the ship and the position in the array
            var testey:Number = Math.abs(this.y - caminhoCoords[0][1]);



            if (testey<=velocidade+2 && testex<=velocidade+2) // if is velocidade+2 close then go to the next coordnate
            {
                caminhoCoords.shift();
            }   
        }
    }
```

This function draw the line:

```
    private function desenhaCaminho():void //draw the black Path
    {
        if(caminhoCoords.length>=1) 
        {
            caminho.graphics.clear();
            caminho.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000, 1,true);
            caminho.graphics.moveTo(caminhoCoords[0][0],caminhoCoords[0][1]);
            for (var i:int = 1; i < caminhoCoords.length; i++)
            {
                caminho.graphics.lineTo(caminhoCoords[i][0], caminhoCoords[i][1]);
            }
        }else 
        {
            caminho.graphics.clear();
        }
    }
```

Every time the ship arrive in one coordinate is take that coordinate off the array and redraw the array.

Is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: I doubt you'll find someone to dig through hundreds of lines of code for you. What did you try to narrow down the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe if you set your registration point of the plane to the centre and use `.snapto(path)`, it will improve the action.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.The post might answer the question.Little more explanation might help out the fellow programmers to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from just the look of the stuttering, I would guess you need to smooth out the "line" a fair bit. It's probably picking up a lot of noise in the line, which is then translated into the rotation of the plane. Either smooth out the rotation/position of the plane, or the line itself.